# Undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for #<Array: for nested model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a nested form with three models `vehicle`, `vehicle_key_feature` and `vehicle_detail` where `vehicle_key_feature` and `vehicle_detail` has one to one relation with `vehicle`. It is working fine when I use strong params following way -

```
params.require(:vehicle).permit(:title, vehicle_key_feature_attributes: [:android_auto], vehicle_detail_attributes: [:tech_specs])
```

since I have lots of strong params for all three models, I would like to keep nested attributes params in a separate method and merge them with vehicle_params. But it's showing me following error

> undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for #Array`

I have written the following codebase, I checked console and  params.inspect which is in expected form.

```
  def vehicle_params
    params.require(:vehicle).permit(
      :title, :category_id, :make, :model, :model_number, :mileage, :exterior, :interior, :transmission, :engine_type, :drivetrain, :fuel_efficiency, :engine, :condition, :description, :dealer_id          
    )
    .merge(vehicle_key_feature_attributes)
    .merge(vehicle_detail_attributes)   
  end

  def vehicle_key_feature_attributes
    {
      vehicle_key_feature_attributes: [
        :android_auto, :apple_carplay, :backup_camera, :blind_spot_monitor, :bluetooth,   
        :forward_collision_warning, :interior_accents, :keyless_entry, :side_impact_air_bags
      ]
    }
  end

  def vehicle_detail_attributes
    {
      vehicle_detail_attributes: [ 
        :exterior, :interior, :entertainment, :mechanical, :safety, :tech_specs, :details
      ]
    }    
  end
```

What is the best solution to extract these two nested attributes in two separate methods?

Answer (score 2):

Your second snippet is doing something else. To replicate what the first one does, add your hashes to permit's argument list.

```
params.require(:vehicle).permit(:title, ..., vehicle_key_feature_attributes.merge(vehicle_detail_attributes))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working now with your snippet.